# How to create a textbox in C# to look like the one in Outlook search

Tags: c#, winforms

In Outlook 2013, a user can type a word into the search field and then after the results are displayed, modify the type of search by clicking the arrow in the search box and specifying "To", "From", "Subject", "Any", etc

how can I mimic that triangle with the options. I'd like to use my own search options.

Comment: IMO everybody will not be knowing Outlook2013 text field. Provide some image to make more clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Sriram if you need images, I'll upload a few but the search is also the same as Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better off designing a control in WPF and hosting it in your WinForms window. In WPF it will be really easy to custom the textbox.

Comment: Which part specifically?

Comment: How do l design a WPF control and then use it in a WinForm

Comment: Project->Add New Item->WPF->User Control. Then you need to drag in an ElementHost from the toolbox (under WPF Interoperability) to your WinForms form. Click the little arrow at the top right, and in the "Select Hosted Content" dropdown select your WPF UserControl.